# "Bother and do" for "bother doing/to do" in colloquial speech and writing

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms

As far as your English variety goes, does it sound acceptable to say "bother and do" instead of "bother doing/to do" in colloquial speech and not so formal writing?

E.g.

*Please spend a moment of your time to **bother and read***...
http://800notes.com/Phone.aspx/1-416-640-3489/2

*It impressed you enough to **bother and reply***...
http://www.flickr.com/groups/capturenx/discuss/72157634028025270/

*If you are black and voted for Barry, did you **bother and look***...
http://darrenyancy.com/2012/11/07/you-were-forewarned/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never encountered this usage and I find it odd. But evidently some people are using it (presumably on the analogy of *try to do* <-> *try and do*).

I think you have captured a snapshot of Language in transition.

Comment: Exactly. I don't suppose there are many people who can honestly say they find *try **and** do it* "odd" today - though are still plenty who think it's "wrong" to a greater or lesser degree, despite the fact that it's been reasonably common since long before they were born. Currently, I've got to say *bother and [do something]* sounds "wrong" rather than merely "odd" to me - but I suppose if I encountered it often enough, that would change.